How to change the url of the archive page to be inside the custom post type
I made the custom post type named "News" and I have a static page load for url.com/news
Currently, the archive page loads with this url: url.com/?post_type=news
How do I make it so that the archive page will load using this url: url.com/news/all-news
Note: I'm using elementor

The has_archive parameter for registering the post type should work (untested):
register_post_type( 'news', array(
    ...
    'has_archive' => 'news/all-news',
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug'       => 'news',
        'with_front' => false,
    ),
) );

Remember to flush the permalinks by going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking Save button.

Worth noting that it also requires rewrite to not be false and with_front to be false to get the desired URL structure.

Nice, @ChrisCox: updated.
